# Metric space and closed sets (book misprint?)

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I am not sure if there is a misprint in this corollary or if I am not getting the idea right.

Corollary. Let $X$ be a metric space and let $A\subset X$. Then A is closed in $X$ iff:
$$
(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset A \text{ and } x_n \rightarrow x \text{ implies } x_n \in A
$$
Shouldn't it be $x \in A$ instead of $x_n \in A$? If not, why?

Comment: Yes you are correct. $A$ is closed if it contains all its limits points, not the sequence again. Actually there is another typo. It should say $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty} \in A$, which is an element of the set. Also, what book is this from? May want to send an email to the author(s) for errata.

Comment: Those are the lecture notes from a former lecturer of the course I am doing at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is a misprint.